# nested foreach loop in php for query

Tags: php, sql, foreach, nested-loops

Im trying to insert data in my db. It should look something like this --

```
     a_id=1 s_id=1 q_id=1
     a_id=1 s_id=1 q_id=2
     a_id=1 s_id=2 q_id=1
     a_id=1 s_id=2 q_id=2
```

right now it inserts something like this --

```
     a_id=1 s_id=1 q_id=null
     a_id=1 s_id=2 q_id=null
     a_id=1 s_id=1 q_id=1
     a_id=1 s_id=1 q_id=2
     a_id=1 s_id=2 q_id=1
     a_id=1 s_id=2 q_id=2
```

I have been beating my head around it for quite a long time. Please let me know if some one can shed some light on this. Here's my code --

```
    $aid=$_GET['id'];
    $sdata=XYZ::model()->findAll('a_id=:aid',array(':aid'=>$id));
    $qdata=ABC::model()->findAll('a_id=:aid',array(':aid'=>$id));
    $sql='insert into assignment_answers
                (a_id, s_id, q_id)
                values (:aid, :sid, :qid)';
            $command1=$connection->createCommand($sql);
            foreach($sdata as $sd)
            {
                foreach($qdata as $qd)
                {
                    $sid=$sd->id;
                    $command1->bindParam(":sid",$sid,PDO::PARAM_STR);
                    $qid=$qd->id;
                    $command1->bindParam(":qid",$qid,PDO::PARAM_STR);
                    $command1->bindParam(":aid",$aid,PDO::PARAM_STR);
                    $command1->execute();
                }
            }
```

Comment: Where and how did you define $sid, $qid, and $aid?

Comment: Where are $sid, $qid and $aid?

Comment: @Aioros have edited my question.

Comment: As far as the scope of your code goes here, there is nothing suspicious. (apart from that scary unvalidated $_GET var) What do $sdata and $qdata contain? Impossible to debug without knowing what they contain.

Comment: Have you verified the contents of $sdata & $qdata to have the data you expect it to have?

Comment: Your resulting data makes no sense. Like @ThaMe90 says: try to verify if your data is as you expect. var_dump() the $sd->id and $qd->id in the loop to check if they're set as expected.

Comment: And are you sure this is the entire code block? The first two resulting rows are not generated in the loop (assuming `->id`'s are primary keys). I'm having the feeling you are doing another insert in some other part, or running this code block at least twice.

Comment: Sorry, another comment, `$id` is not being set, are you aware?

Comment: @ThaMe90 I have checked using print_r function. It has the data i want.

Answer (score -1):

You need 3 foreach loops: 1 for $adata, 1 for $sdata & 1 for $qdata.

```
$sql='insert into assignment_answers
            (a_id, s_id, q_id)
            values (:aid, :sid, :qid)';
$command1=$connection->createCommand($sql);
foreach($adata as $ad)
{
    foreach($sdata as $sd)
    {
        foreach($qdata as $qd)
        {
            $command1->bindParam(":aid",$ad->id,PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $command1->bindParam(":sid",$sd->id,PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $command1->bindParam(":qid",$qd->id,PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $command1->execute();
        }
    }
}
```

I assumed you also have a $adata set like $sdata & $qdata.

Comment: Seems $aid gets set by a knowningly $_GET['aid'] variable.

Comment: Ah, yeah, I missed that one.